# Applying a function over a Single lm object with a list of predictor variables

Tags: r, purrr, mapply

I am trying to create a visualize_lm function that returns the list of all effect_plots of all predictor variables in the lm() and also outputs figures with 4 graphs max on the plot screen.

Here are my variables and the code I've tried so far.

```
summary(samsung_multifit)



Call:

lm(formula = samsung ~ ., data = stockNfirm[-(2:11)])

Residuals:

     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-10052.6  -1861.0    -32.9   2175.9   7301.3 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -3.877e+04  9.186e+02 -42.208  < 2e-16 ***
sse         -1.309e+00  1.873e-01  -6.991 3.58e-12 ***
nikkei      -3.730e-01  5.092e-02  -7.326 3.27e-13 ***
kosdaq      -1.770e+01  1.449e+00 -12.214  < 2e-16 ***
kospi        2.518e+01  6.109e-01  41.212  < 2e-16 ***
dji          2.171e+00  5.400e-02  40.199  < 2e-16 ***
Individual  -2.548e-01  8.726e-02  -2.920  0.00354 ** 
Foreigner   -2.399e-01  8.386e-02  -2.861  0.00426 ** 
Institution -1.976e-01  8.569e-02  -2.306  0.02119 *  

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3197 on 2287 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9098,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9095 
F-statistic:  2884 on 8 and 2287 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

`pred_string <-names(samsung_multifit$model)[-1]`

```
 pred_string

[1] "sse"         "nikkei"      "kosdaq"      "kospi"       "dji"        

[6] "Individual"  "Foreigner"   "Institution"
```

`

```
> str(samsung_multifit)
List of 12
 $ coefficients : Named num [1:9] -3.88e+04 -1.31 -3.73e-01 -1.77e+01 2.52e+01 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:9] "(Intercept)" "sse" "nikkei" "kosdaq" ...
 $ residuals    : Named num [1:2296] 818 640 452 430 464 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2296] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ effects      : Named num [1:2296] -1487856 156486 385095 75598 201526 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2296] "(Intercept)" "sse" "nikkei" "kosdaq" ...
 $ rank         : int 9
 $ fitted.values: Named num [1:2296] 14322 14820 15148 15170 15136 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2296] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ assign       : int [1:9] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 $ qr           :List of 5
  ..$ qr   : num [1:2296, 1:9] -47.9166 0.0209 0.0209 0.0209 0.0209 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2296] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:9] "(Intercept)" "sse" "nikkei" "kosdaq" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:9] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  ..$ qraux: num [1:9] 1.02 1.01 1.03 1 1.01 ...
  ..$ pivot: int [1:9] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  ..$ tol  : num 1e-07
  ..$ rank : int 9
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
 $ df.residual  : int 2287
 $ xlevels      : Named list()
 $ call         : language lm(formula = samsung ~ ., data = stockNfirm[-(2:11)])
 $ terms        :Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language samsung ~ sse + nikkei + kosdaq + kospi + dji + Individual + Foreigner + Institution
  .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(samsung, sse, nikkei, kosdaq, kospi, dji, Individual, Foreigner, Institution)
  .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:9, 1:8] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:9] "samsung" "sse" "nikkei" "kosdaq" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:8] "sse" "nikkei" "kosdaq" "kospi" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:8] "sse" "nikkei" "kosdaq" "kospi" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:8] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(samsung, sse, nikkei, kosdaq, kospi, dji, Individual, Foreigner, Institution)
  .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:9] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:9] "samsung" "sse" "nikkei" "kosdaq" ...
 $ model        :'data.frame':  2296 obs. of  9 variables:
  ..$ samsung    : num [1:2296] 15140 15460 15600 15600 15600 ...
  ..$ sse        : num [1:2296] 2602 2599 2589 2592 2592 ...
  ..$ nikkei     : num [1:2296] 9510 9626 9626 9602 9566 ...
  ..$ kosdaq     : num [1:2296] 481 483 484 484 484 ...
  ..$ kospi      : num [1:2296] 1812 1827 1833 1833 1833 ...
  ..$ dji        : num [1:2296] 10595 10608 10754 10761 10739 ...
  ..$ Individual : num [1:2296] -1428 -4237 -289 -289 -289 ...
  ..$ Foreigner  : num [1:2296] 2051 2722 1320 1320 1320 ...
  ..$ Institution: num [1:2296] -331 1645 -1116 -1116 -1116 ...
  ..- attr(*, "terms")=Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language samsung ~ sse + nikkei + kosdaq + kospi + dji + Individual + Foreigner + Institution
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(samsung, sse, nikkei, kosdaq, kospi, dji, Individual, Foreigner, Institution)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:9, 1:8] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:9] "samsung" "sse" "nikkei" "kosdaq" ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:8] "sse" "nikkei" "kosdaq" "kospi" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:8] "sse" "nikkei" "kosdaq" "kospi" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:8] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(samsung, sse, nikkei, kosdaq, kospi, dji, Individual, Foreigner, Institution)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:9] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:9] "samsung" "sse" "nikkei" "kosdaq" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
```

I've tried using for loops, map, apply functions and had no luck so far.

```
visualize_lm <- function(lm_model ){

  for(i in 2:length(lm_model$model)){
    q <- effect_plot(samsung_multifit, pred =!!(pred_string[i]), interval = TRUE, plot.points = TRUE)
  }

  result <- mapply(FUN = effect_plot, samsung_multifit, MoreArgs = list(quote(pred_string))) 

  grid.arrange(q,q1,q2,q3, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
  grid.arrange(q4,q5,q6,q7, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)

  rm(list = c("q","q1","q2","q3","q4","q5","q6","q7"))
}
```

I hope the function will output a list of effect_plot objects and also print multiple figures with most 4 effect_plots with y axis samsung and x axis dji (dow jones index).

---

P.S.
OMG I managed to make the function I want. Would there be a way to speed up this function?

```
visualize_lm <- function(lm_model ){

  pred_string <-names(lm_model$model)[-1]
  return_list <- list(length(pred_string))


  for(i in 1:length(pred_string)){
    q <- effect_plot(lm_model, pred = !!(pred_string[i]), interval = TRUE, plot.points = TRUE)
    return_list[i] <- list(q)
  }

  nCol <- floor(sqrt(length(pred_string)))
  do.call("grid.arrange", c(return_list, ncol=nCol))
  return(return_list)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something that hopefully meets your requirement, by using the mtcars data. My code is shown below. Hope it helps.

```
library(jtools)
library(gridExtra)

mtcars <- mtcars[, 1:9]

MyModel <- lm(mpg ~ ., mtcars)

pred_string <- names(MyModel[["model"]])[-1]

for(i in 1:length(pred_string)){
  assign(paste0("q", i), effect_plot(MyModel, pred =!! pred_string[i],
                                 interval = TRUE, plot.points = TRUE))
}

grid.arrange(q1, q2, q3, q4, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
grid.arrange(q5, q6, q7, q8, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

That being said, there are a few things that did not go as expected in your code.

For example, you have only assigned the plots to the object "q", therefore you do not have "q1" through "q7" at all.

Another thing is that it causes a great deal of confusion when you are combining a function, a loop, and apply statements all together. It can be very hard to decipher what you are trying to achieve.